# Advantages of Hash Verification of Parameters and Content over TLS

Tags: security, ssl, hash

When researching approaches to securing web services, I found an application that hashes portions of the URL in addition to utilizing TLS. I also found a specification that proposes to verify the body of the request by producing a hash and verifying the content server side (specification follows):

[Final: OAuth Request Body Hash](https://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/spec/ext/body_hash/1.0/oauth-bodyhash.html)

In the specification, it mentions:

> Nonce checking and the use of https can mitigate this risk, but may not be available in some environments. Even when nonce checking and https are used, signing the request body provides an additional layer of defense.

Looking at the OAuth 2.0 specification, it seems as though they have deemed these steps unnecessary when an application is properly configured/coded, instead relying on TLS to provide the security features, of which, I believe, includes tamper proofing. While there has been criticism with this specification from people like the former lead author, it has also been said (by the same person) when properly implemented, it is secure.

Is there any real benefit to these hashing procedures? Are there known attacks that would compromise a web service that only utilizes a Nonce and TLS to verify validity?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from a quick read of the documentation (I don't specifically know much about OAuth), you are confusing the purpose of the hash. The inclusion of the hash is meant to extend the signature covering other parts of the request to the body:

> The OAuth Core specification provides body integrity checking only for application/x-www-form-urlencoded request bodies. Other types of request bodies are left unsigned.

Note that just including the hash in the URL does not provide any additional security. Instead, what they do is include it in the part that is signed:

> 3. Set the oauth_body_hash parameter to the obtained value.
> 4. Sign the request as per [[OAuth Core 1.0] section 9](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process). The oauth_body_hash parameter MUST be included in the Signature Base String together with the other request parameters.

Thus, their statement "Even when nonce checking and https are used, signing the request body provides an additional layer of defense." refers to the practice of signing the URL parameters (among other stuff) via RSA (or "signing" it via HMAC) and thus also authenticating the body via the included hash. If the URL parameters are not signed (the "PLAINTEXT" method is used), you do not gain any additional security by including a hash of the body.